# Is there a simpler solution to this basic nonhomogeneous system?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE system:

$\frac{dN_i}{dt}=a_i\left(1-\sum_iN_i\right)$

where $i \in [0, 1, \dots, I]$ I'm aware that there is a general solution to this by rewriting it in the form $\mathbf{N}'=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{N}+\mathbf{b}$. However, since the RHS of this system of equations is almost identical for all rows aside from the constant $a_i$, is there a simpler solution to this system of equations? I ask because I am trying to solve this repeatedly for very large $I$, so being able to avoid any expensive matrix computations would be ideal.

Comment: write an ode for $\sum N$

Comment: That has the straightforward solution $\sum N(t) = 1 - ce^{-t\sum a}$ but I'm not sure how this helps me? I've been able to use this to find a solution for the specific system where $i \in [0, 1]$ but I'm not sure how to generalise it.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm being an idiot. it's easy to generalise after that point. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For this DE, there is indeed an efficient way to do it.

First, define $N = \sum_{i = 1}^I N_i$. Then

$$\begin{eqnarray} \frac{dN}{dt} & = & \frac{d}{dt} \sum_i N_i \\
& = & \sum_i \frac{dN_i}{dt} \\
& = & \sum_i a_i(1 - \sum_j N_j) \\
& = & \sum_i a_i(1 - N) \\
& = & (1 - N) \sum_i a_i
\end{eqnarray}$$

This is a very simple separable DE that you can solve for $N$. Once you've done that, you can substitute the expression you get for $N$ into the individual DEs and solve them directly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestions by [@ConMan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82793/conman) and [@user619894](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/617446/user619894), we firstly solve for $N(t)=\sum_i N_i(t)$ (using the initial condition $N(t=0)=N_0$ and letting $A=\sum_i a_i$):

$N(t)=1-(1-N_0)e^{-At}$

Then substituting $N(t)$ into the original system, using the initial condition $N_i(t=0)=N_{0,i}$:

$N_i'(t)=a_i\left(1-N(t)\right)$

$N_i'(t)=a_i(1-N_0)e^{-At}$

$N_i(t) = -\frac{a_i}{A}(1-N_0)e^{-At}+c$

$N_i(t) = \frac{a_i}{A}(1-N_0)\left(1 - e^{-At}\right)+N_{0,i}$